# Is there any way to export google maps driving directions as a series of gps coordinates?

Tags: google-maps, export, gps

Is there a good way of taking google maps' driving directions and exporting them as a series of GPS coordinates detailing the route? Any help you can provide is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the tool at [Maps to GPX](https://mapstogpx.com/).

Get a share link for your route on Google Maps, then paste it into that website. It will give you a download for a GPX file, containing the directions as a track or route.

Some more details on the developer's blog: [Converting Google Maps Directions to GPX data](https://blog.sverrirs.com/2015/08/converting-google-maps-directions-to.html)

Comment: This worked great! Thanks for your help.